# How to disable Command+Shift+R?

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut

I have been using command+shift+R in Sublime Text forever (super+shift+R in Sublime). On my iMac all that happens is that I hear a beep (on Sierra).

It is really annoying and I can't find a way to remove the shortcut or remap it. Anything I've tried so far hasn't yielded any results.

Karabiner isn't working in Sierra and I tried some other app BetterTouchTool that doesn't seem to help either.

Is there a way to force my Mac to unbind that shortcut?

Comment: If it beeps, it is unbound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A beep indicates that the shortcut that was pressed was not interpreted by apps on the system. This means the shortcut is *already* unbound, so it seems you're having some problem with Sublime Text itself rather than the shortcut being bound to something else.

Comment: You were right! It was another application that stole it.

Comment: Be Focused Pro in my case.

Answer (score -2):

systempreferences-keyboard-shortcuts-appshortcuts: add sublime with the +